# Can a fresher look at Design Thinking program?

Tags: design

My son completed his engineering graduation.  I am exploring a career around design or UX.  Can I suggest him Design Thinking program for him or UX ?  I need guidance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about User Experience, but asking for a job recommendation.

Comment: I think it is a great question which lots of people ask me. I would love to be able to point people to answers on this.

Answer (score 1):

Ask not what a program can do for your son. Ask what your son would like to learn and what career he would like to pursue.

Meanwhile, feel free to post more details about which Design Thinking programs and which UX programs he is considering. It's hard to answer question that's too general.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackExchange, your question is a bit broad are you looking for advice for your son or also for yourself? How would you currently rate your experience in UX design?

With any career it good to pick something you like, this way you will always have fun when you are working and you will spend more time learning new things! Regardless here are some tips I can give you.

If you are starting out and do not have a lot of experience in UX or Design it might be best to focus on one aspect before trying to combine them.

### Tools

UX and Design both use a different amount of tools. Some tools can be used for both paths and others are mainly for either UX or Design.

#### Design tools

These are the main tools I have worked with for design.

- Photoshop CC (Mainly used for the final stages in design)
- Illustrator CC (Great tool if you want to create vector images)
- Affinity Designer (Powerful editing program for vectors and pixel images)

#### UX tools

I use these tools mostly for mockups.

- Paper (The paper you use for printing etc. Super fast to create wireframes and/or mockups)
- Sketch (Great tool for nearly anything UX related. Sadly only on Mac)
- Figma (Online tool for Mockups)
- Balsamiq (Free tool, I recently started using this)

### Learning

A big part in UX and in Design is to improve yourself, you can do this by looking at other designs or taking some courses. You will learn the most by doing everything.

#### Inspiration

- Behance (Great website for inspiration)
- Awwwards
- Pintrest

#### Courses

Here you can learn more about Design thinking

- [Edx](https://www.edx.org/)
- [NNGroup](https://www.nngroup.com/)
- [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/)

#### Personal experience regarding courses/programs

I am currently enrolled in a [design thinking course of RIT](https://www.edx.org/micromasters/design-thinking), while I like the content at the moment it only recently started so I can not form a complete opinion yet. But other courses on edx like the [UX course of Michigan university](https://www.edx.org/micromasters/michiganx-user-experience-ux-research-and-design) were great and helpful.

I always advice people to share and look for peers on the internet. I always give interns at work the following tips: Buy books about UX/Design, Do 5 second tests, Be active and ask for feedback from peers, Bookmark interesting articles for reading.

(For others feel free to edit my post for more examples or websites that you used for learning)

Comment: You have not understood the question. It is not about UX Design. It is about Design Thinking.

Comment: Both, I believe he asked multiple questions at once. 'suggest Design Thinking / UX program?' and 'I need advice?' (given that he specifically stated that he just started exploring in UX). I covered both in my answer, I gave him the advice to start something he liked and later I covered a few websites where he could learn UX and/or Design Thinking. Regardless I will change the answer a bit to reflect more on Design Thinking.